# Convert MySQLdb return from tuple to string in Python

Tags: django, mysql-python

I am new to MySQLdb. I need to read values from a pre-defined database which is stored in MySQL. My problem is when values are collected, they are in tuple format, not string format. So my question: Is there a way to convert tuple to string?

Below are the details of my code

```
import MySQLdb

#get value from database
conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "123", "book")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT koc FROM entries")
Koc_pre = str(cursor.fetchone()) 

#create a input form by Django and assign pre-defined value
class Inp(forms.Form):
    Koc = forms.FloatField(required=True,label=mark_safe('K<sub>OC</sub> (mL/g OC)'),initial=Koc_pre) 

#write out this input form
class InputPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
         html = str(Inp())
         self.response.out.write(html)
```

The output is in tuple format "Koc=('5',)", but I want "koc=5". So can anyone give me some suggestions or reference book I should check?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're only going to be retrieving one value at a time (i.e. getting one column using cursor.fetchone()), then you can just change your code so that you get the first element in the tuple.

```
Koc_pre = str(cursor.fetchone()[0])
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I need to retrieve more than one value (I might take one row at a time)?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way to deal with that is to manually assign values to the tuple (`id = tuple[0]`, `col1 = tuple[1]`, etc.). I'd suggest writing a general MySQL command function that submits the query and returns a tuple. That way you can deal with the returned tuple more easily where you need to.

Comment: Thank you. Also any recommended books Python-MySQL project?

Comment: I don't know of any books specifically about Python and MySQL. My only suggestion would be to bone up on Python and MySQL independently. The actual interaction through the MySQLdb API is pretty straightforward once you get the hang of it.

Comment: how about null values? I get this: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable